# Парсер simplehtmldom. Загрузка страницы

Tags: php, парсер, javascript

Пытаюсь парсить [телепрограмму](http://tv.yandex.ru/49/channels/) с яндекса (список каналов) через библиотеку simplehtmldom, я написал:

```
require 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';    
$html = file_get_html('http://tv.yandex.ru/49/channels/');

echo $html;
```

Но он мне не выводит даже саму страницу, он выводит загруженную страницу, но там пишется, что "Для работы страницы необходимо включить Javascript", он у меня и так включен. Что не так?

Comment: Где у тебя javascript включен? В браузере?))

А внутри file_get_html что?

Comment: PHP работает на сервере. Там JS может быть выключен:)

Comment: - вместо file_get_contents нужно
   curl-ом

Answer (score 1):

Предпочту вариант парсинга с первоисточника - http://www.s-tv.ru/old/tv/. Парсится без проблем.